# How to achieve 15 columns in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout design clearly made for [1200px / 15 cols framework](http://1200px.com/), but my client wants to use Bootstrap. Is it even possible to transform Bootstrap into 15 cols layout? I havent seen such an example online. I'm not a huge fan of Bootstrap for small projects. It is a trend I honestly don't understand. Might be too heavy for a 5 pages website & projects are usually done according to the content, not according to some framework, Twitter-backed or not.

But, this is it.

If it would be possible to code a 15 cols layout, could you give me a hint on how to begin? And how long would it take to perform such an adaptation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run a customized version of Bootstrap, xengravity's answer is the way to go.

However, if you're using vanilla bootstrap (perhaps from a CDN or legacy code) you could create the desired effect with a little CSS tweaking and some nested rows/columns.

Start with a 3 column layout of col-xs-4, then fill those with a `row` and 5 col-xs-* (I chose 3 as it was close) and tweak the width with some CSS. For example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 fixed">1</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 fixed">2</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 fixed">3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 fixed">4</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 fixed">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        . . .
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.col-xs-3.fixed {
    width:20%;
}
```

For an interactive example, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sharf224/owbxw4ax/).

A cleaner way to go would be to include the CSS/LESS from the `col-xs-3` and just make a `fixed-col` or similar class.

**Update**
The funkiness with the columns wrapping/spacing as mentioned in the comments is due to the columns' default padding making it too large for the row and wrapping. As seen in this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sharf224/owbxw4ax/3/) removing the padding for the `.fixed` columns fixes it. This may not be desirable, and as such tweaks will need to be made for your specific application.

Comment: There is some funkyness going on with your example on my end.  Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90.

http://i.imgur.com/jiXv4a2.png

Comment: @xengravity I noticed that too. It has to do with the way bootstrap's rows and columns work, I'm looking for a way around it, but if the project is a fixed large (around 1200px) piece as OP suggested, then you won't have to worry about it as it only seems to happen when the size gets scrunched.

Comment: Thanks both for your help! I'm coding vanilla, so I might wanna use the tweak, but on smaller screens it gets weird as noticed. To customize it takes a lot of time and makes the CND unusable.

Comment: @designarti check out my update, I fixed the problem. You may need to tweak the rows/columns to suit your specific needs.

Comment: I would like to point out that having 15 columns on the size screen that forces the wrap would be impractical to say the least.

Comment: I got it after pressing enter. Thanks a lot! Looks good from here too!

Answer (score 4):

You can customize and download your own Bootstrap components by going to:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

and navigating down towards the "grid-columns"

[image]

Set your preferred number of columns and scroll to the bottom to click "Compile and Download".

I would generally recommend going with an even number of columns over odd however for easier math.

Comment: I agree with an even number of columns. I'd suggest 30 with the standard unit being 2 cols....if that makes sense. Hard to do a half screen split with 15 cols.